# Python - how to write a script that computes the sum from 0 to a number; start at the number and work down

Tags: python

Hi I want to write a script that computes the sum from 0 to a number starting at the number and work down. So far I wrote:

```
num=0
tot=0
n=5
while n>=num: 
    tot=tot+n
    n=n-1
print(tot)
```

not working

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation. Minimal, complete, verifiable example applies here.  Specifically, *how* is this not working?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What exactly is not working? Please read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Since you recently joined, you should also check the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get good answers to your questions.

Comment: Which one of both gives the correct solution: `sum(range(n, 0, -1))`  or `sum(range(n-1, 0, -1)`?

Comment: @Junia Compostella your code works for me. I get `15`. With starting number `5`, counting to `0`, `5+4+3+2+1` = `15`? What is not working with your code?

Comment: ... I guess I had issues with my notebook because it was not printing anything even with refreshing. code works fine. sorry for the trouble. and thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

`sum(range(n+1))` where n is your number

Answer (score 0):

You can try following script.

```
sum = 0
num = 3
# use while loop to iterate un till zero
while(num > 0):  
    sum += num  
    num -= 1  
print("The sum is",sum)
```

Output:

```
The sum is 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need to count down?
By calculating the sum of a range you get the desired output.

```
n = 5
sum = sum(range(0, n+1)) # as python does not include the last int in range
print(sum)
```

Comment: Ok as I typed @Mikedev just posted the same answer